# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. when building the application in production mode in angular7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular7 application which works fine in developement mode.But when i try to create a production version i am getting an error as like this.

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
src/app/video/video.component.ts(56,35): error TS2339: Property 'videoUrl' does not exist on type 'number | VideoName | (() => string) | { (...items: ConcatArray<VideoName>[]): VideoName[]; (...items: (VideoName | ConcatArray<VideoName>)[]): VideoName[]; } | ((searchElement: VideoName, fromIndex?: number) => number) | ... 25 more ... | (() => IterableIterator<...>)'.
  Property 'videoUrl' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

The code which the error show is here:

```
 Object.keys(this.quality).map((key) => {
    this.departments.push({id: key, name: this.quality[key].name, videoUrl: this.quality[key].url});
  });
```

Though i have used an model for type

```
export class VideoName {
id: number;
name?: string;
videoUrl?: string;
}
```

Full Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import { VideoName } from './model';
import { find } from 'lodash';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-video',
  templateUrl: './video.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video.component.scss']
})
export class VideoComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('videoPlayer') videoplayer: ElementRef;

  departments?: VideoName[] = [];

  public videoPath: string;
  public title: string;
  public plot: string;
  public englishTitle: string;
  public tamilTitle: string;
  public posterImage: string;
  public quality: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log('params is', params);
      this.videoPath = params["url"];
      this.title = params["title"];
      this.plot = params["plot"];
      this.englishTitle = params["subtitles_en"];
      this.tamilTitle = params["subtitles_ta"];
      this.posterImage = params["poster"];
      this.quality = JSON.parse(params["quality"]);
      Object.keys(this.quality).map((key) => {
        this.departments.push({id: key, name: this.quality[key].name, videoUrl: this.quality[key].url});
      });
    });

  }

  changedata($event){
    let id = $event.target.value;
    let selectedData = find(this.departments, {id: id});
    this.videoPath = selectedData.videoUrl;
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.load();
    this.videoplayer.nativeElement.play();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me where i am wrong.

Comment: You'll need to put complete component code as this.departments is absurd

Comment: @BlackMamba Can you pls check my updated code

Comment: From my experience I say that your IDE can help you more than you think. Just check you configured it properly and the version of your checker is the same of your builder. Then, also check that you are importing `VideoName` correctly

Comment: key is string, use +key to convert to number push({id: +key,...}

Comment: @Eliseo it is correct i am getting the id as type string

Answer (score 0):

@Nidhin Kumar, change your class something like below,

```
export class VideoName {
    id: number;
    name?: string | number;
    videoUrl?: string | number;

    constructor(id,name,videoUrl){
      this.id=id;
      this.name=name;
      this.videoUrl= videoUrl;
    }
}
```

this approach will take both `string` or `number` as type of the variable.

**UPDATE**

> **change this**

```
this.departments.push({id: key, name: this.quality[key].name, videoUrl: this.quality[key].url});
```

> **like below**

```
this.departments.push(new VideoName(key,this.quality[key].name,this.quality[key].url));
```

Comment: I have changed but while building it for production facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution according to me should be convertin url to string whatever it may be so

```
this.departments.push({id: key, name: this.quality[key].name, videoUrl: this.quality[key].url+''});
```

Might help you fix the issue